# Is it possible to use CSS to have mouse over image zooming to the point of the cursor?

Tags: html, css

We have a portfolio on a website, and the images are quite high resolution, however only the full image is displayed on the screen, and on small screens, this isn't enough to see the detail.

I am looking to see if there is a way to use pure CSS to zoom into the image to where ever the cursor is. I know you can use the following to zoom in the image, however this is not quite the effect we're looking for.

```
.image:hover img {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.25);
}
```

Is there an alternative without java script to zoom in the image?

Comment: why not? isn't it zooming?

Comment: @giorgio It will zoom, but not to the point of the cursor, we're looking for something more like this: http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/.

Comment: ah, in that case pure css-solution is a no go. You'll have to write some javascript, or use [one of the numerous](https://www.google.com/webhp?#q=javascript%20zoom%20image%20on%20mouseover) ready made solutions

Comment: In short, no, you cannot, since CSS is not aware of the mouse's position.

Comment: @giorgio Thanks, I thought it may not be possible, I'll look at using JQuery to do the job, perhaps the solution I found. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

You must use Jquery/Javascript to do that, css can't know where are your mouse...

```
<script>
$(function() {
$("#idOfImage").hover(function(e) {

  var offset = $(this).offset();
  var relativeX = (e.pageX - offset.left - myConst);
  var relativeY = (e.pageY - offset.top - myConst);

  //now you've got X, Y position.
  this.css( "background-position", relativeX.toString()+" "+relativeY.toString());
  this.css("height", this.css("height")*myZoom);
  this.css("width", this.css("width")*myZoom);
});
});
</script>
```

Doc: http://api.jquery.com/css/

put a html div :

```
<div id="idOfImage"></div>
```

css:

```
#ifOdImage{
    [...]
    background-position: 0 0;
    [...]
}
```

doc: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Comment: That's a click solution, OP wants a hover solution.

Comment: So how do we zoom? This is only getting the location.

Comment: if you get position you can modify css background image position.

Comment: i've modify my answer to fit to you're question, sorry i've just would to guide you on solution way...